# React native view auto height

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I have a component with 3 views inside, one in the top, other in the middle, and the last one in the bottom. The view in the middle has a specific height. I want the others to adapt their height. Know this has to be easy but I am not too good with flex...

Here is my code:

```
export default function Cropper({ photo }) {
  const { colors } = useTheme();

  const [height, setHeight] = useState(WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <BlurView intensity={100} style={{ flex: 1 }} /> {/* auto height */}
      <View style={[styles.cropper, { height: height }]} />
      <BlurView intensity={100} style={{ flex: 1 }} /> {/* auto height */}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "flex-start",
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
  cropper: {
    width: "100%",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<View style={[styles.cropper,{height:height}]}/>
```

to

```
<View style={styles.sec}/>
```

and change

```
cropper:{width:'100%'}
```

to

```
cropper: {
    width: '100%',
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height/2,
}
```

and add

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'
```

Comment: That is my problem. This view will not have any children. I just want to make a blurred view in the top and buttom, but adapting their height to the middle's one

Comment: Then your code is correct keep both `flex:1`. Does your middle View height is working properly?

Comment: I am thinking is that your height value is passing as NaN. Try printing height value, if height is working good then its working fine.

Comment: Actually my height is setted to Dimensions.get("window").height / 2, not NaN when printing

Comment: Welcome bro. If you feel this is correct you can upvote my answer.

Comment: Getting this msg from stackoverflow: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." I suppose thats because I signed up few days ago.  But it says I have upvoted it.